# Count how many times user has loaded a page on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if I can count the times user loads pages on my site, with JavaScript. Probably like this?

```
var pageloads = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageloads =++
});
```

But where would I store it? In a cookie?

Comment: If you store it in a cookie, it only counts how many times that one user has visited, not all users. If that is enough info for you, cookies will work fine.

Comment: Yeah a cookie or Local DB, from which I think cookie is easier because you can tell its expiration length.

Comment: @kevinb yeah, per one user, but how would I store it in a cookie and update it every time?

Comment: A cookie is local to the current browser installation. eg: Firefox on my pc gets one cookie, opera on my pc gets another, my phone gets another, etc. Tracking methods are much more abstract than tracking an actual user, unless you're doing some crazy cross-referencing of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If older browsers like IE7 and below are'nt an issue, you can use local storage:

```
$(function(){
     var loaded = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('loaded'), 10),
         loaded_numb = loaded?loaded+1:1;
     localStorage.setItem('loaded', loaded_numb);

     $('body').append('<p>This page was loaded by you '+loaded_numb+' times !');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FERC/1/)

Comment: You have a typo in your code btw, it it adds 1 to front of the number. Like first you get 1, then 11, 111...

Comment: As the others are pointing out, this is not really persistent, global or anything else. It tracks the number of times the page was loaded by that user in that browser etc.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - forgot to parse the returned string as integer, fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

Easier to just do it with cookies (especially since there's no reason to totally block out IE7 and lower)

```
var numLoads = parseInt(getCookie('pageLoads'), 10);

if (isNaN(numLoads) || numLoads <= 0) { setCookie('pageLoads', 1); }
else { setCookie('pageLoads', numLoads + 1); }

console.log(getCookie('pageLoads'));
```

getCookie/setCookie simple get/set functions (can be found in the jsFiddle)

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGKm3/1/)**

Comment: Well, I don't think that you can use adblock on IE7 so local storage will do fine too! But thanks!

Comment: Ahh okay didn't know that's what you were trying to do. Why you hating on adblocker anyway? :P

Comment: I'm not hating it, I just want to kill a kitten everytime I see adblock.

Comment: And I'm notifying the user that a kitten has been killed :)

Comment: Hahah niiice. I've seen a few sites have even background images (behind their ads) that are like "Oh hey coolguy, adblock pro goooood call." amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a database.  If you are looking for monitoring the traffic on your web page you should look at Google Analytics http://www.google.com/analytics/.

They show you how many people visited your site, whether they are new or returning, the path they took through your site, bounce rate etc.  Best part is it's free.

Comment: I know about google analytics, but it's not for that kind of purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this with Javascript?  Whatever server you're using should have access logs that store all requests, IPs that make the requests, and a lot more.  There are even free log file analyzers like awstats and Google Analytics.  You should do this on the server side, not the client side.

If you *really* want to store it with JavaScript, then your only options are a cookie and LocalStorage -- both of those are quite transient.

Comment: I'm using it as a part of adblock detection.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible - edit: to track an actual user.

You can only ever track a particular instance of a browser using cookies.

There is no such thing as tracking a "user" using javascript alone. You can reliably count things like user logins though.

Comment: I have. All they do is increment a number in a cookie on a unique browser. It doesn't tell you the information you're asking about.

Comment: The question was "count the times user loads pages on my site, with JavaScript", I'd say some of the answers answer that question perfectly, there was nothing about persistent global count serverside in that question ?